# How To convert .mp4 to HLS(.m3u8) format

Tags: android, android-studio, video-streaming, android-ffmpeg

I want to convert .mp4 video to HLS(.m3u8) format. I am using https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg library to achieve our task. I am creating a method for achieve the task.

```
fun convertFileInHLS(sourceFilePath: String, destFilePath: String, context: Context) {

    val desFilePath = getVideoDir(context)!!.path
    val desFinalFilePath = File(desFilePath, "filename.m3u8").path
    val hlsFileCommand = "ffmpeg -i ${sourceFilePath} -codec: copy -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls ${desFinalFilePath}"
    //val hlsFileCommand = "-i ${sourceFilePath} -c:v mpeg4 ${destFilePath}"
    Log.i(TAG, "hlsFileCommand:${hlsFileCommand}")
    //-i file1.mp4 -c:v mpeg4 file2.mp4
    val executionId = FFmpeg.executeAsync(hlsFileCommand) { executionId, returnCode ->
        Log.i(TAG, "executionId:${executionId}")
        if (returnCode == RETURN_CODE_SUCCESS) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Async command execution completed successfully.")
        } else if (returnCode == RETURN_CODE_CANCEL) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Async command execution cancelled by user.")
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, String.format("Async command execution failed with returnCode=%d.", returnCode))
        }
    }
}
```

and I am using FFmpeg command

> val hlsFileCommand = "ffmpeg -i ${sourceFilePath} -codec: copy -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls ${desFinalFilePath}"

In which `sourceFilePath`=

> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.arthenica.mobileffmpeg.test/files/video/2021_0417_001639.mp4

and `desFinalFilePath`=

> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.arthenica.mobileffmpeg.test/files/video/2021_0417_001639.mp4

When I run this code then it returns **executionId=3003 and return code=1** .

Comment: `desFinalFilePath` *…_001639.* ***mp4*** looks off

Comment: Did you manage to solve this one @greybeard?